# Object Reference Not set to instance of an object - SSRS on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I see there's been quite a few topics covering this error on Sharepoint, but not quite one where it happened to someone who's been using SSRS.

So I have this report which users need to access, with most of them it opens fine and they can use it.

But recently, two new users can't open the report.

They get the following error:

[image: Image to Screenshot]

I tried to google and see whats wrong, but I cant find anything.

Comment: I think you have to re-start the sharepoint services. We use to get that error once every 4-5 weeks. That is the easiest fix. Has nothing to do w/ ssrs

Comment: Thanks for that @junketsu, will try that for sure.